# PHP Return value from Inner class

Tags: php, methods, return

I have this question in my mind which still confuses me. I have class in PHP, which has methods which manipulate values by calling other methods of the same class. All those functions return some sort off values by "return" statement. But the problem arises when i call any number of functions for manipulation it always ends the script by the first function call.
For example

(Sorry for Psuedo Code)

```
Class H
Method1
$this->Method2()
$this->Method3()
Method2
Returns something
Method3
Returns something
End
```

When im using method1 from the script, which in case calls two other methods, which have a return value.  My script ends while its on Method2 inside Method1.

Comment: can you post sample code or something that we can look at to explain it better?

Comment: Not for right now, but i want to ask it is a good approach to use echo stmt while returning something? Because the scripts get ends when i call the method2 inside method1, i also want to use method3 after method2 is executed

Answer (score 0):

That's because `return` kills the process and returns what you want. You could have internal properties of the class and retrieve those. Methods that set those properties are called `setters` and methods that retrieve them are called `getters`. Take a look at this example class:

```
<?php

Class MyClass {

    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $city;

    // Setters
    public function setFirstName($name)
    {
        $this->firstName = $name;
    }

    public function setLastName($name)
    {
        $this->lastName = $name;
    }

    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;
    }

    // Getters
    public function getFullName($name)
    {
        return "{$this->firstName} {$this->lastName}";
    }

    public function getCity($name)
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

}
```

Now, because I set those properties I could easily instantiate my class and grab that info:

```
$class = new MyClass();

$class->setFirstName('David');
$class->setLastName('Parker');
$class->setCity('AnyTown');

echo $class->firstName; // David

echo $class->lastName;  // Parker

echo $class->city; // AnyTown

// or something like

echo $class->getFullName(); // David Parker
```

If you want to simply echo data, it may make more sense to instantiate the class and echo the class's property. I find it's usually good practice to `return` something from a class. You would be better off using `echo` when working with that class object.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I know getters and setters, but thanks. You have demonstrated by instantiating a class and then manipulating it. What if i would have to manipulate the values from other functions of the same class, without actually instantiating it. I hope u got it?

Comment: I don't want to echo it buddy, it simply prints on the browser

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to learn the basics of OOPS in PHP..especially return type of an method,method overloading and overriding..
http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/php-objects-page-3/
I hope this one makes you feel better...if my ans doesn't sounds well don't your questioning...keep searching..it ill be a tricky one..

Comment: I had already learned all those stuffs in oops. This kills my mind actually!

Comment: i took a brief on yours..its going like a loop..finally when you call one method this loop start from the first..so it gives prior to the first method...does it fill  your question?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I dont want my script to end over there

Comment: then you have to use method overloading..it never ends..but we can pick the desired method through parameter..isn't it??

Comment: Nope! Exactly.  I just want to manipulate anything.  But dont want my script to echo it or end in failure